# How to get href with an element handle in puppeteer js

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

I have the following element:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="compareItemsExpand" data-id="5338402">
    1977 Appleton Foxes TCMA #1 Appleton Foxes Staff
</a>
```

I need to get the `href` of this element.  I have the element handle I'm looping over.

```js
const elementHandles = await page.$$(".title a");
    
for (const elHandle of elementHandles) {
    const elHref = await elHandle.getAttribute('href');
    console.log(elHref);
    // ...
}
```

This appears empty.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting it like this:

```
const elHref = await page.evaluate(anchor => anchor.getAttribute('href')
```